# CORS problems with Springboot and Angular Websocket

Tags: spring, websocket, sockjs

I have two service to build a Spring Boot application

But I always got CORS problems like this

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '.../websocket-cr/info?t=1581585481804' from origin'http://localhost:8080' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. 
The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials.
```

**Springboot service on 8082**

```
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
       registry.addEndpoint("/websocketcr").
       setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080").withSockJS();
    }
```

**Angular service on 8080**

```
    var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/websocket-cr');
    //socket.withCredentials = true ;
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
```

I have tried

```
    setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080").withSockJS();
    setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
```

or use **CORS Anywhere in javascript**

```
    var socket = new SockJS('http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://localhost:8082/websocket-cr');
    socket.withCredentials = true ;
```

and what is the best way to done that

should I make angular proxy to my backend server?

or it is ok by setAllowedOrigins('host:port')

Comment: It is work after I add "socket.withCredentials = true ;"

Comment: ref https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

Comment: @a4fz067lu what did you do to fix this? anything you added to CORS config in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 0):

In your Main class of the SpringBoot service , inject the below bean,it will work

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer () {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE").allowedHeaders("*")
                    .allowedOrigins("*");
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for coming late to this Party.
I am using here STOMP JS in `angular 8` with `springboot`
[working demo](https://github.com/RameshMF/angular8-springboot-websocket)
you need to add `WebSocketConfig` class to configure things for Socket and For controller separately if you need it.

**Configuration Class**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
        .setAllowedOrigins("*")
        //.setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200").setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:8081")
        .withSockJS();
    }
}
```

ref [Another Help from Spring people](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/)

In **Controller Class** just add

```
@Controller
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class LogsController {
..
}
```

And answer will be updated for authentication/authorization sooner and later.

Comment: ref    
https://github.com/RameshMF/angular8-springboot-websocket

Answer (score -3):

Simply just add **@CrossOrigin** annotation on top of the class. It's work perfectly. For example:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class YourController {
    .....
}
```