# Why CORS problem on AWS still occur after I set AllowedOrigins "*"

Tags: angular, networking, websocket

After I solved these problems

[CORS problems with Springboot and Angular Websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60205312/cors-problems-with-springboot-and-angular-websocket)

These two server is functioning properly at localhost

and I'm going to put backend-Server on ECS

[client-localhost] <---> [Aws application LoadBalancer]  <---> [ECS-websocketServer]

I changed setup and SockJS URL as it should be.

It is good connect to websocketServer(ECS) when I start clientServer on localhost

```
"ng serve  --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check"
```

but CORS occurred while start clientServer on LAN（192.168.x.x）

```
"ng serve  --host 192.168.x.x --disable-host-check"
```

Is there a network setting problem?
But I thought I had set universal AllowedOrigins

```
registry.addEndpoint("/websocket-cr").setAllowedOrigins( "*" ).withSockJS();
```

---

Even though I put my clientServer on ECS, and set DNS

[ECS-clientServer] <---> [Aws application LoadBalancer]  <---> [ECS-websocketServer]

```
registry.addEndpoint("/websocket-cr").setAllowedOrigins( "myclientDNS" ).withSockJS();
```

It still had CORS problem,
Could someone do me a favour?

Comment: Check the content type. It's case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set all the following headers and not only access control origin for CORS to work

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * 
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER, Content-Type
```